# How to count and fetch data query in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to merge this two queries ?

```
$data = DB::table('category_to_news')
      ->where('category_to_news.name', ucwords($category))
      ->remember(1440)
      ->count();
```

and

```
$data = DB::table('category_to_news')
      ->where('category_to_news.name', ucwords($category))
      ->remember(1440)
      ->get();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you just need to know how many results you got, you don't need to run another query. Just call `$data->count()`.

Comment: i want to count all row and get `title` field value from table `category_to_news` , with count tehe query will be optimize

Comment: @user3395037 as @Quasdunk said, just do the second one of those, and use `$data->count()` to get the count. It doesn't do an SQL `COUNT(*)` but instead simply counts the results returned in the `$data` array.

Answer (score 2):

So, as far as I understand from your comment, you simply want to get *all* records from the table `category_to_news` and you want to know how many records are in there, right?

MySQL's `count` is an aggregate functions, which means: It takes a set of values, performs a calculation and returns a *single* value. If you put it into your names-query, you get the same value in each record. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with 'optimization'.

As already said, you simply run your query as usual:

```
$data = DB::table('category_to_news')
      ->where('name', ucwords($category))
      ->remember(1440)
      ->get(['title']);
```

`$data` is now of type `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which provides [handy functions for collections](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html), and one them is `count()` (*not to be confused with the above mentioned aggregate function - you're back in PHP again, not MySQL*).

So `$data->count()` gives you the number of items in the collection (which pretty much is an array on steroids) without even hitting the database.

Answer (score 1):

Hi DB class dont return collection object it give error "call member function on array" but eloquent return collection object. for above code we can use collect helper function to make it collection instance  then use count and other collection methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods .

```
$data = DB::table('category_to_news')
      ->where('name', ucwords($category))
      ->remember(1440)
      ->get();
$data = collect($data);

$data->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You my get it using:

```
$data = DB::table('category_to_news')
          ->where('name', ucwords($category))
          ->remember(1440)
          ->get();
```

To get the count, try this:

```
$data->count();
```

Why you are using `DB::table(...)`, instead you may use `Eloquent` model like this, create the model in your `models` directory:

```
class CategoryToNews extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'category_to_news';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // if different than id then change it here
}
```

Now, you may easily use:

```
$data = CategoryToNews::whereName(ucwords($category))->get();
```

To get the count, use:

```
$data->count();
```